# Display current requests with Nginx

Tags: nginx

How to know what nginx handles exactly now?

I search for request uri, request start time, request headers and another info.

I could not use access log becaise it contains only finished requests.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx provides only the total numbers of accepted, dropped and active connections in the community builds. The complete description of statistics provided is [here](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_status_module.html).

Commercial builds provide more information, but frankly I don't see anything that would match your needs. The documentation is [here](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_api_module.html).

Answer (score 0):

NGINX provides overall stats with [`stub_status on;`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_stub_status_module.html) but if you want to get some details for each request you can use a custom lua module to log requests. You can find details of lua modules https://nginxtutorials.com/nginx-lua-module/